# Database security consideration while developing app for mobile

Tags: asp.net, html

we are developing app in asp.net HTML5 css3 for Iphone and Ipad. Its database driven web app. I want to know what are the best pracices to access DB from Mobile client. What are the database security considerations? What are the security risks that I should consider whaile developing such app that will run on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're developing in asp.net, which is a web framework, the same security considerations should be made as a normal web application.

Answer (score 0):

As it's a web application, mobile or desktop isn't relevant.

Microsoft have a a great website covering [Security Considerations for ASP.NET Web Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984187%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), I would suggest you give this a good look over and implement these into any websites you build.

The only things you need to consider whilst building a mobile website is responsive design, and restrictions on the browser.

**Responsive Design:**

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-responsive-web-design

**Browser Restrictions**

For browser restrictions you will have to look around but for example up to iOS 5.x.x you couldn't upload using an input tag, and obviously in iOS you won't be able to download unsupported file types to the device.

**Accessing from Client**

As with any application where a client is accessing a database with other client data in it, input sanitation is a must.

*E.g a link to change a document is like Document.aspx?ID=4*

Don't assume that the user wouldn't change the ID in the URL just to see what happens, always do checks for everything the user attempts.

Comment: Thanks Ryan...Can please suggest me any tutorial/Weblink for responsive design and restriction on browser for Mobile app?

Comment: Thanks Ryan...One more question is what are the security threats if we directly access databases from client instead of any business layer?